# python 2 axis pattern recognition for raspberry pi

Tags: pattern-recognition

Just after some tips to where maybe head for further info.

But basically so confused prob better just to explain.

4 infra red diodes up, down, left, right gives up/down left/right ratio's.
I wish to record simple gestures such as left right up down and an algorithm that will match the pattern over a time base.

Needs to be relatively low in process load as using a Pi0w but just wondering with so many options available what maybe suggested as currently drowning in Google.

Is it neural or sci-kit and just something relatively simple like linear regression.

I have a data plot over time of up/down & left/right ratio's short 20 - 30 byte plots and would like to try and provide a little accuracy in recognition.